# creating new new lines from column values

Tags: r, loops, dataframe

I'm struggling with one thing: I have an R dataframe with individual ID, entry year and exit year for each individual. It looks like:

```
id  Entry  Exit  
1   1988  1990  
2   1986  1987
```

I need a new dataframe where the interval (entry, exit) is expanded into the years it contains, ie I need this:

```
id Year  
1  1988  
1  1989  
1  1990  
2  1986  
2  1987
```

I have not been able to create the right loop and I'd be very grateful for your help.
Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
d <- structure(list(id = c(1, 2), Entry = c(1988, 1986), Exit = c(1990, 
                1987)), .Names = c("id", "Entry", "Exit"), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                      -2L), class = "data.frame")

years <- apply(d, 1, function(x) seq(x[2], x[3]))
ids <- rep(d[, "id"], lapply(years, length))

res <- cbind(ids, unlist(years))
res

# ids     
#[1,]   1 1988
#[2,]   1 1989
#[3,]   1 1990
#[4,]   2 1986
#[5,]   2 1987
```

Comment: Thank you Ari and Luciano,this solves the problem. The only inconvenience is that my dataframe has 4000 lines so the vectors id, Entry and Exit defining d are going to be quite long!  But thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Two options here:

1. Build a data.frame in an apply-style command, then stack the small dfs into a large one afterwards.
2. Or use the apply-style command to handle the year expansion and calculate how many times the IDs need to be repeated afterwards.  This is what @LucianoSelzer does in his elegant response.

Either way works fine.  Here's an example of the former.

```
dat <- data.frame(id=seq(2),entry=c(88,86),exit=c(90,87))
res <- apply(dat,1,function(x) data.frame(id=x[1],year=seq(x[2],x[3])) )
> res
[[1]]
  id year
1  1   88
2  1   89
3  1   90

[[2]]
  id year
1  2   86
2  2   87
```

`res` is now a list of data.frames.  Then we can combine the data.frames:

```
library(taRifx)
> stack(res)
  id year
1  1   88
2  1   89
3  1   90
4  2   86
5  2   87
```

Or in base R:

> do.call(rbind,res)
>     id year
>   1  1   88
>   2  1   89
>   3  1   90
>   4  2   86
>   5  2   87

Comment: Try it without loading `taRifx`...base R has no suitable method for lists of data.frames.

Comment: You could also make a `do.call(rbind, res)`

Comment: For sure.  There's some error checking and label handling that `taRifx::stack.list` does that mean I have a slight preference for it.  Plus syntactically it just reads better to me.  But point well-taken.  I've updated the answer to reflect the base R solution.